# UAC prompt electron when installing app in admin and non-admin user

Tags: windows, electron, nsis, uac, electron-builder

below are our electron and builder versions,

"electron": "13.1.7"
"electron-builder": "22.11.9"

in electron-builder file, our configuration have
"win": {
"requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator"
}

and nsis configuration as below,

```
"nsis": {
        "warningsAsErrors": false,
        "installerIcon": "assets/icon.ico",
        "runAfterFinish": true,
        "oneClick": true,
        "perMachine": false,
        "installerHeader": "assets/installerHeader.bmp",
        "installerSidebar": "build/installerSidebar.bmp",
        "createDesktopShortcut": true,
        "include": "build/installer-qa2.nsh",
        "artifactName": "${productName}.${ext}"
    }
```

as per above config, we have supported our application for both admin and non-admin user

we are facing 2 issues :-

1. at time of installing app in admin user -> asking UAC prompt only with Yes and No option,
   and every time running application, asking same prompt
2. at time of installing app in non-admin user -> not asking UAC prompt with admin credentials, app gets installed properly,
   but every time we run application after exit it, its asking UAC prompt every time

What we want to achieve -

1. in 1st point mentioned above, running app every time it should not ask for UAC prompt with Yes and No buttons
2. in 2nd point mentioned above, it should ask UAC prompt with admin credentials only at time of install/uninstall application,
   it should not ask for UAC prompt every time we run the application

Can anyone please help us out to achieve as per above mentioned points?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Does your program actually _require_ elevation when you run it after it is installed? (And if, so, why?)

Comment: I have had a similar problem in the past. Before the .exe file of you installer is being run, Windows checks if the file being executed, is an installer, if it is the UAC prompt will appear every time. Here are the checks that Windows runs to see if your application requires a UAC prompt: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works#installer-detection-technology). I am guessing your installer file name contains one of the keywords "install," "setup," or "update", in wich case the UAC will appear.